# Unable to click on Cross Button in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am unable to click on cross(`close`) `icon` in rebus given pic .

Using below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("otp")).sendKeys(password);
driver.findElement(By.id("verifyUser")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal']//iframe[@class='modalIframe']"))).close();
```

[image: Highlighted button]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Your code is switching to a frame and closing it... you can't close the frame. You need to `.click()` the X in the dialog. You probably should do some more googling and reading. There are plenty of code examples and other questions you can refer to. Once you've done that, update your question with your current attempt and the results.